# nodejs retry function if failed X times

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, callback, async-await

I want my function to execute X(=3) times until success.

In my situation I'm running `kinesis.putRecord` (from AWS API), and if it fails - I want to run it again until it succeeds, but not more than 3 tries.

I'm new to NodeJS, and the code I wrote smells bad.

```
const putRecordsPromise = function(params){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        kinesis.putRecord(params, function (err, data) {
            resolve(err)
        });
    })
}

async function waterfall(params){
    try{
        let triesCounter = 0;
        while(triesCounter < 2){
            console.log(`try #${triesCounter}`)
            let recordsAnswer = await putRecordsPromise(params)
            if(!recordsAnswer){
                console.log("success")
                break;
            }
            triesCounter += 1;
        }
        // continue ...

    } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
}

waterfall(params)
```

I promise the err result. Afterwards, If the err is empty, then all good. otherwise, continue running the same command.

I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, all the Aws functions can return a Promise out of the box, then you can just put the call into `try/catch`:

```
let triesCounter = 0;
while(triesCounter < 2){
    console.log(`try #${triesCounter}`)
    try {
        await kinesis.putRecord(params).promise();
        break;  // 'return' would work here as well
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
    triesCounter ++;
}
```

Comment: it throws `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @TheCrystalShip, in your question you had the code in an `async` function, so it is assumed you put this answer-code in the `async` function.

Comment: Pit my snippet into your `waterfall` function. It is already `async`

Comment: Another improvement would be using a clasic `for` loop, instead of `while`.

Comment: @trincot as far as we want to execute code only till it succeeds, I find `while` here better, as `for` with `break` could be confusing...

Comment: The advantage of `for (let ...` is that the loop variable has block scope within the loop only. Not sure why `break` would be more confusing in a `for`. It is what `break` is for.

Comment: @trincot I think it's just a taste thing, your point is valid.

Answer (score 8):

In functional style:

```
...
await tryUntilSucceed(() => kinesis.putRecord(params).promise());
...

async function tryUntilSucceed(promiseFn, maxTries=3) {
    try {
        return await promiseFn();
    } catch (e) {
        if (maxTries > 0) {
            return tryUntilSucceed(promiseFn, maxTries - 1);
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a little module, say `try-and-try-again.js`:

```
exports = module.exports = tryAndTryAgain;

function tryAndTryAgain( maxTries, thisContext , fn, ...argv) {
  let success = false;
  
  for (let i = i ; i < maxTries && !success ; ++i ) {
    let rc = fn.apply(thisContext, args);
    success = rc == 0 ? true : false;
  }
  
  return success;
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere:

```
const tryAndTryAgain = require('./try-and-try-again');

function somethingThatMightNeedARetry() { ... }

const succeeded = tryAndTryAgain( 3 , null, somethingThatMightNeedARetry, 'arg-1', 'arg-2', 'arg-3' );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `npm` package called [async-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-retry) that is pretty handy. It acts as a wrapper for your function and retries if anything throws (with some exceptions that you can handle, see their example below).

```
// Packages
const retry = require('async-retry')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
 
await retry(async bail => {
  // if anything throws, we retry
  const res = await fetch('https://google.com')
 
  if (403 === res.status) {
    // don't retry upon 403
    bail(new Error('Unauthorized'))
    return
  }
 
  const data = await res.text()
  return data.substr(0, 500)
}, {
  retries: 5
})
```