# nodejs sendMessage function if failed X times

Tags: node.js, promise, callback, async-await, slack-api

I want my function to execute X(=3) times until success.

I know this question looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031780/nodejs-retry-function-if-failed-x-times) but none of that answers helped.

I just want to send this message to slack and if it fails then try again for 3 times.

```js
const options = {
    'text': 'Hello'
  }

let flag = 0
  function sendMessage () {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post(webhookURL, JSON.stringify(options))
        .then(response => {
          flag++
          return resolve('SUCCESS: Sent slack webhook', response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return reject(new Error('FAILED: Sent slack webhook', error))
        })
    })
    return promise
  }

  for (let maxRetry = 0; maxRetry < 3; maxRetry++) {
    const p = sendMessage()
    p
      .then((status) => {
        console.log(status)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    console.log('flag', flag)
    if (flag >= 1) {
      break
    }
  }
```

It runs for 3 times even after it was successful. The promise is not working properly
output

```
flag 0
flag 0
flag 0
SUCCESS: Sent slack webhook
SUCCESS: Sent slack webhook
SUCCESS: Sent slack webhook
```

I am new to nodejs. It will be very helpful if anyone of you could help me here.

Comment: I updated the question. Please see again. I am stuck here. If it fails , it fails for 3 times and if it runs it runs for 3 times. It is not stopping after first succes.

Comment: The problem is that the loop is finished before the flag is even updated once, and that because its an asynchronous execution, that's why you get all flags as 0 .... so the standard loop wont work in this example

Comment: So what should I do to run it properly. How can I make it synchronous. Can you please write an answer to make it work properly.

Comment: Checkout the solution in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution using `async/await` feature, and this will allow you to wait for the promise to resolve before running another call to the asynchronous function

**Example with success:**

```js
//const axios = require('axios');

function sendMessage() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .then(response => {
        resolve('SUCCESS: Sent slack webhook', response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(new Error('FAILED: Sent slack webhook', error));
      });
  });
}

(async function loop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log('loop count = ', i);
    try {
      const res = await sendMessage();
      console.log(res);
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**Example with error:**

```js
//const axios = require('axios');

function sendMessage() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get('https://falseurl')
      .then(response => {
        resolve('SUCCESS: Sent slack webhook', response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('FAILED: Sent slack webhook')
        reject(new Error('FAILED: Sent slack webhook', err));
      });
  });
}

(async function loop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log('loop count = ', i);
    try {
      const res = await sendMessage();
      console.log(res);
      break;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```